# Waiting for Process to terminate on a remote PC using for loop

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd, parentheses, wmic

Should be able to sort this but I'm going round in circles. I know this has to do with setlocal
EnableDelayedExpansion, but I'm missing something.

Goal:
Execute a windows (cleanmgr.exe) script on a remote machine, wait till Cleanmgr.exe closes then have
the initiating script "type" the resultant log file (generated via cleanup script) from the remote
system in the CMD window.

What's working:
The script running on the remote machine runs fine, it echo's C: free drive space into a log file,
then cleans up the PC, and then re runs the disk space report and echo's result into same log file,
so the user can see (/have transparency of) the reclaimed space via the before & after results.

What's Broken:
The WMIC command to check for Cleanmgr.exe on the target PC, only works once, when it waits to retry
the variable containing the Hostname has been wiped out. I can see the behavior by echoing the
variable back.

Fix Attempts:
I have a hunch this has to do with the variable being lost once the if statement is ran within the
Parentheses. I have tried lots of options but they all behave the same. I have tried jumping the
process out to loop outside the original code using %1 instead of %%i but just cant quite get there.

Thanks for any improvements.

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
color 1e
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
title HDD Space Checker...
for /f %%i in (hostnames.txt) do (
xcopy /y cleanupwindows-sfd.bat \\%%i\C$\IT
WMIC /node:"%%i" process call create "C:\IT\cleanupwindows-sfd.bat"
echo Waiting For Processes...
timeout -t 10 /nobreak >nul
:loop
WMIC /node:"%%i" process where name="cleanmgr.exe" get name |find "cleanmgr.exe">nul
IF "!errorlevel!"=="0" set running=var
IF "!running!"=="var" timeout -t 4 >nul & echo Still Running & goto :loop
IF "!running!"=="" timeout -t 4 >nul & type \\%%i\C$\IT\%%i_HHD_Space.log
)
pause
exit
```

Comment: You cannot use labels within a for loop.

Comment: @Compo IIRC, in the earlier time (DOS 3.0/3.2..), we had a very basic FOR command with which we can do multiple statements with `&` but no parenthesis block. The `GOTO` command was then thought to branch unconditionally and then exit the `FOR` cycle. I guess MS has kept it like that even _within_ the parenthesis to keep compatibility with old scripts.

Comment: You could use the [WaitFor](https://ss64.com/nt/waitfor.html) command in your parent and child batch files to communicate with each other as well.

Comment: For anyone interested, there is a web implementation of IBM PC-DOS ( 3.2 too and many others) [here](https://www.pcjs.org/software/pcx86/sys/dos/ibm/3.20/). I still remember how to exit IBM BASIC with the `SYSTEM` command... It's unfair, years only bring xp and pains... Anyway, the `FOR` command works as i remember: `FOR %I IN (A B C) DO ECHO %I` is ok, but `&` nor `CALL` were not there in 3.2.. (Since 3.3 for `CALL`, i guess W95 for `&`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is at least two points to see.

1. Your `running` variable, once set,  is never reset, triggering an infinite loop
2. Your `goto` statement inside the enclosing parenthesis drives the command interpreter (cmd.exe) to stop evaluating the block, thus your script loose the `%%i` and leave the for loop, thus when terminating the `:loop` cycle your script will leave the for loop without cycling to other values in `hostnames.txt`.

To address that, put your process code in a subroutine called with `CALL` and reset the `running` variable at each `:loop` cycle :

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
color 1e
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
title HDD Space Checker...
for /f %%i in (hostnames.txt) do (
  CALL:Process "%%i"
)
pause
exit
:Process
xcopy /y cleanupwindows-sfd.bat \\%~1\C$\IT
WMIC /node:"%~1" process call create "C:\IT\cleanupwindows-sfd.bat"
echo Waiting For Processes...
timeout -t 10 /nobreak >nul
:loop
set "running="
WMIC /node:"%~1" process where name="cleanmgr.exe" get name |find "cleanmgr.exe">nul
IF "!errorlevel!"=="0" set "running=var"
IF "!running!"=="var" timeout -t 4 >nul & echo Still Running & goto :loop
IF "!running!"=="" timeout -t 4 >nul & type \\%~1\C$\IT\%~1_HHD_Space.log
GOTO:EOF
```

Explanations: The `CALL` statement implies that the command interpreter will store the current executed line of your script and its state before executing the associated subprocess/command/etc.. When the subprocess/command/etc.. finishes, the command interpreter resumes its execution of the script to the next line with a restored context. This avoids then the loose of the for loop context.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Valuable explanation too. Appreciate it.